# Как сохранить контакт из моей БД в телефонные контакты?

Tags: sqlite, uri

У меня есть приложение, в которое заносятся клиенты и сохраняются в мою базу данных. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, выбранный контакт сохранялся в контактах телефона. Помогите пожалуйста. Этот код не работает с БД, заносит только написанные в коде данные.

```
case R.id.addContTelefonItem:  // добавление контакта в телефон

            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    ContactsContract.Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse());
            intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, ContactDBmoy.COLUMN_NAME);
            intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.COMPANY, "Квартирант");
            intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, ContactDBmoy.COLUMN_PHONE);
            startActivity(intent);
```